# How to sort K sorted arrays, with MERGE SORT

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I know that this question has been asked, and there is a very nice elegant solution using a min heap.

MY question is how would one do this using the merge function of merge sort.

You already have an array of sorted arrays.  So you should be able to merge all of them into one array in O(nlog K) time, correct?

I just can't figure out how to do this!

Say I have

[ [5,6], [3,4], [1,2], [0] ]

Step 1: [ [3,4,5,6], [0,1,2] ]

Step2:  [ [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] ]

Is there a simple way to do this?  Is O(nlog K) theoretically achievable with mergesort?

Comment: Each of the N elements has to be placed into the output, so you cannot do this faster than O(N)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging sorted arrays, what is the optimum time complexity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116043/merging-sorted-arrays-what-is-the-optimum-time-complexity)

Comment: OMG how do you want to do that in O(log K) when you have to "read" each item at least once? Do you even know what logarithm means?

Comment: I've always used more of a tournament sort for this -- extract the first element of each array, sort them, place the first sorted element in your output array, then remove it from the sort list and replace it with the next element from the removed element's array.  Requires a sort of key sort of the list of first elements, but, given the way this works, a plain old bubble sort works well for that (since you only need one pass after each replacement).

Comment: @HotLicks: That gives you O(M.K^2) (where M is the number of elements per list).  I think you can get O(M.K.log(K)) by maintaining some kind of min-heap of next elements.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke I meant n log k where n is the number of elements total in all arrays

Comment: I know the min heap way. I just want to know if it can be done with equal time complexity with merging arrays.

Comment: @ordinary: I am talking about merging.  But you need some mechanism to determine which is the next element to append to the output array.  I think a size-K min-heap is better than a sorted size-K array.

Comment: No I understand your way. It is better for sure. I'm saying. Is there a way to merge each component array.

Comment: @ordinary: I **am** talking about merging.

Comment: I understand your way and it is indeed superior to hot licks suggestion. I'm asking if there is a way to use merge each component array into a larger sorted array in each step. So you have 4 arrays then 2 arrays then 1 areay

Comment: The steps shown in your question are the answer: you merge each pair of arrays and then repeat, resulting in an O(n logk) total runtime. What else do you need to know?

Comment: How do you implement this? Try as I might i can't seem to find a way to inplement this algorithm although I can implement merge sort on a single array

Comment: @interjay are sure its possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have said, using the min heap to hold the next items is the optimal way. It's called an N-way merge. Its complexity is O(n log k).

You *can* use a 2-way merge algorithm to sort k arrays. Perhaps the easiest way is to modify the standard merge sort so that it uses non-constant partition sizes. For example, imagine that you have 4 arrays with lengths 10, 8, 12, and 33. Each array is sorted. If you concatenated the arrays into one, you would have these partitions (the numbers are indexes into the array, not values):

```
[0-9][10-17][18-29][30-62]
```

The first pass of your merge sort would have starting indexes of 0 and 10. You would merge that into a new array, just as you would with the standard merge sort. The next pass would start at positions 18 and 30 in the second array. When you're done with the second pass, your output array contains:

```
[0-17][18-62]
```

Now your partitions start at 0 and 18. You merge those two into a single array and you're done.

The only real difference is that rather than starting with a partition size of 2 and doubling, you have non-constant partition sizes. As you make each pass, the new partition size is the sum of the sizes of the two partitions you used in the previous pass. This really is just a slight modification of the standard merge sort.

It will take log(k) passes to do the sort, and at each pass you look at all n items. The algorithm is O(n log k), but with a much higher constant than the N-way merge.

For implementation, build an array of integers that contains the starting indexes of each of your sub arrays. So in the example above you would have:

```
int[] partitions = [0, 10, 18, 30];
int numPartitions = 4;
```

Now you do your standard merge sort. But you select your partitions from the `partitions` array. So your merge would start with:

```
merge (inputArray, outputArray, part1Index, part2Index, outputStart)
{
    part1Start = partitions[part1Index];
    part2Start = partitions[part2Index];

    part1Length = part2Start - part1Start;
    part2Length = partitions[part2Index-1] - part2Start;

    // now merge part1 and part2 into the output array,
    // starting at outputStart
}
```

And your main loop would look something like:

```
while (numPartitions > 1)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < numPartitions; p += 2)
    {
        outputStart = partitions[p];
        merge(inputArray, outputArray, p, p+1, outputStart);
        // update partitions table
        partitions[p/2] = partitions[p] + partitions[p+1];
    }
    numPartitions /= 2;
}
```

That's the basic idea. You'll have to do some work to handle the dangling partition when the number is odd, but in general that's how it's done.

You can also do it by maintaining an array of arrays, and merging each two arrays into a new array, adding that to an output array of arrays. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Thank you! A legitimate answer.  How do you implement merge sort with non-standard partition sizes?  The way I do it is recursively kind of like a post order traversal where it goes to the bottom of the tree and merges 2 and doubles and so on.  I can't figure a way to modify this version for non standard partition sizes

Comment: i have a question, wouldn't this try to merge inputArray into outputArray all the time? however partially-merged arrays would be in outputArray

Comment: @epipav: You have to do some work to switch the input/output arrays on successive calls. The logic isn't difficult. I didn't include that detail because it wasn't particularly pertinent to the larger discussion.

Comment: i see, thank you for the general idea tho, it helped me a lot

Comment: Don't you think time complexity for k arrays with size n, with your proposed way (using Min heap) will be O(nk logk), and not O(n logk)?

Comment: As I understood, in the question it is said all arrays are sorted and we only need to merge them. But I think your solution sort them as well, right?

Comment: (I heard the optimal way to merge sorted k arrays is using Min Heap, which has time complexity of O(nk logk). So, if your solution is merging k sorted arrays and has O(n logk), yours will be the optimal one.)

Comment: @Hengameh: No, my solution does not sort the individual arrays. It only merges. As far as I know, this merge algorithm and the one using min-heap are both O(n log k). I do not know where you get the O(nk log k) value.

Comment: Sorry! I was confused 2 questions!   1. we have `k sorted arrays`, each of them with `size n`. Time complexity of this one using Min Heap would be `O(nk logk)`.   2. we have `k sorted arrays`, size of all of them `all together is n`. This version is the one that you proposed this nice solution. and as you said time complexity is `O(n log k)`.

Comment: @Hengameh: Time complexity of merging k sorted arrays using a min-heap is `O(n log k)`, *not* `O(nk log k)`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm, or any standard algorithm reference.

Comment: Thank you for the link and clarification

Comment: Unbelievable. Time complexity cannot be better than `O(n * k)` just because we have to deal with each item in matrix, so it cannot be `O(n * log k)`.

Comment: @ValentinShergin: You might want to check your logic. The algorithm I present is indeed O(n log k). Take my example, where we have 4 arrays. They can be merged in two passes. We made log(k) passes over n items. Thus, `O(n log k)`. I don't know what you mean by "deal with each item in matrix." Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh, it makes sense if `n` represents total number of all elements of `k` arrays. I thought `n` is length of each of `k` arrays. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You should note that when we say complexity is O(n log k), we assume that n means TOTAL number of elements in ALL of k arrays, i.e. number of elements in a final merged array.

For example, if you want to merge k arrays that contain n elements each, total number of elements in final array will be nk. So complexity will be O(nk log k).

Answer (score 2):

There different ways to merge arrays. To accoplish that task in N*Log(K) time you can use a structure called Heap (it is good structure to implement priority queue). I suppose that you already have it, if you don’t then pick up any available implementation: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)
Then you can do that like this:

```
1.  We have A[1..K] array of arrays to sort, Head[1..K] - current pointer for every array and Count[1..K] - number of items for every array.
2.  We have Heap of pairs (Value: int; NumberOfArray: int) - empty at start.
3.  We put to the heap first item of every array - initialization phase.
4.  Then we organize cycle:
5.  Get pair (Value, NumberOfArray) from the heap. 
6.  Value is next value to output.
7.  NumberOfArray – is number of array where we need to take next item (if any) and place to the heap.
8.  If heap is not empty, then repeat from step 5
```

So for every item we operate only with heap built from K items as maximum. It mean that we will have N*Log(K) complexity as you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it in python. The main idea is similar to mergesort. There are k arrays in *lists. In function mainMerageK, just divide lists (k) into left (k/2) and right (k/2). Therefore, the total count of partition is log(k). Regarding function merge, it is easy to know the runtime is O(n). Finally, we get O(n*log k)
By the way, it also can be implemented in min heap, and there is a link: [Merging K- Sorted Lists using Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474924/merging-k-sorted-lists-using-priority-queue)

```
def mainMergeK(*lists):
    # implemented by k-way partition
    k = len(lists)
    if k > 1:
        mid = int(k / 2)
        B = mainMergeK(*lists[0: mid])
        C = mainMergeK(*lists[mid:])
        A = merge(B, C)
        print B, ' + ', C, ' = ', A
        return A
    return lists[0]

def merge(B, C):
    A = []
    p = len(B)
    q = len(C)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < p and j < q:
        if B[i] <= C[j]:
            A.append(B[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            A.append(C[j])
            j += 1
    if i == p:
        for c in C[j:]:
            A.append(c)
    else:
        for b in B[i:]:
            A.append(b)
    return A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = mainMergeK([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 10], [9])
    print x
```

The output likes below:

```
[1, 3, 5]  +  [2, 4, 6]  =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 10]  +  [9]  =  [7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  +  [7, 8, 9, 10]  =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like a 2-way merge except with K items. Will result in O(NK). If you want O(N logK) you will need to use a min-heap to keep track of the K pointers(with source array as a metadata) in the algorithm below:

Keep an array of K elements - i.e K pointers showing position in each array.
Mark all K elements are valid.

loop:
Compare values in K pointers that are valid. if the value is minimum, select least index pointer and increment it into the next value in the array. If incremented value has crossed it's array, mark it invalid.
Add the least value into the result. 
Repeat till all K elements are invalid.

For example,:

```
Positions        Arrays
p1:0  Array 1:  0  5  10  
p2:3  Array 2:  3  6   9
p3:2  Array 3:  2  4  6
```

Output (min of 0,3,2)=> 0. So output is {0}

```
      Array
p1:5    0  5  10
p2:3    3  6   9
p3:2    2  4  6
```

Output (min of 5,3,2)=> 2. So {0,2}

```
       Array
p1:5    0  5  10
p2:3    3  6  9
p3:4    2  4  6
```

Output (min of 5,3,4)=>3. So {0,2,3}
..and so on..until you come to a state where output is {0,2,3,4,5,6}

```
   Array
p1:5    0  5  10
p2:9    3  6  9
p3:6    2  4  6
```

Output (min of 5,9,6)=>6. So {0,2,3,4,5,6}+{6} when you mark p3 as "invalid" as you have exhausted the array. (or if you are using a min-heap you will simply remove the min-item, get it's source array metadata: in this case array 3, see that it's done so you will not add anything new to the min-heap)