# Merge Sort with Random Split

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

In Mergesort Algorithm, instead of splitting array into the equal half, try to split array from random point in each call, I want to calculate the average time of this algorithm?

Our notes calculate it as normal merge sort.  any formal idea?

Comment: Will it be the same as usual quicksort is? May be you can just find complexity analysis for quicksort and use it.

Comment: the average length of each half is exactly a half, if your random is uniform. I think that suffice to prove the average time remains nlogn.

Comment: Dear @njzk2, would you please add a formal proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that its time complexity is `O(n log n)`(it's not very formal).

1. Let's call a split "good" if the size of the largest part is at most 3/4 of the initial subarray(it looks this way: `bad bad good good good good bad bad` for an array with 8 elements). The probability of split to be good is `1/2`. It means that among two splits we expect one two be "good".
2. Let's draw a tree of recursive merge sort calls:

   ```
       [a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n]    --- level 1
            /             \
   [a_1, ..., a_k]   [a_k + 1, a_n] --- level 2
       /    \            /  \
   ...                              --- level 3

                                    ...

                                    --- level m
   ```

   It is clear that there are at most `n` elements at each level, so the time complexity is `O(n * m)`.
3. But 1). implies that the number of levels is `2 * log(n, 4 / 3)`, where  `log(a, b)` is a logarithm of `a` base `b`, which is `O(log n)`.
4. Thus, the time complexity is `O(n * log n)`.

Comment: would you please add a bit more detail ?

Comment: I'm not sure about proof exactly :)  I think we must use mathematical proof? am I right?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh If it is your homework, I cannot know what level of rigor is required. I think you should add the info about how formal the proof should be to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about recursive merge sort.

In standard merge sort, you split the array at the midpoint, so you end up with (mostly) same-sized subarrays at each level. But if you split somewhere else then, except in pathological cases, you still end up with nearly the same number of subarrays.

Look at it this way: the divide and conquer approach of standard merge sort results in `log n` "levels" of sorting, with each level containing all `n` items. You do `n` comparisons at each level to sort the subarrays. That's where the `n log n` comes from.

If you randomly split your array, then you're bound to have more levels, but not all items are at all levels. That is, smaller subarrays result in single-item arrays before the longer ones do. So not all items are compared at all levels of the algorithm. Meaning that some items are compared more often than others but *on average*, each item is compared `log n` times.

So what you're really asking is, given a total number of items N split into k sorted arrays, is it faster to merge if each of the k arrays is the same length, rather than the k arrays being of varying lengths.

The answer is no. Merging N items from k sorted arrays takes the same amount of time regardless of the lengths of the individual arrays. See [How to sort K sorted arrays, with MERGE SORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980818/how-to-sort-k-sorted-arrays-with-merge-sort/18984961#18984961) for an example.

So the answer to your question is that the *average case* (and the best case) of doing a recursive merge sort with a random split will be O(n log n), with stack space usage of O(log n). The worst case, which would occur only if your random split always split the array into one subarray that contains a single item, and the other contains the remainder, would require O(n) stack space, but still only O(n log n) time.

Note that if you use an iterative merge sort, there is no asymptotic difference in time or space usage.

Comment: Dear @Jim, what do u mean by  iterative merge sort?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh: You can write merge sort recursively, or as nested loops. See http://www.sinbadsoft.com/blog/a-recursive-and-iterative-merge-sort-implementations/ for an example. Or just do a Google search on iterative merge sort.