# Algorithm on List and Maximum Product

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures, discrete-mathematics

a) with sequence X=(x1,x2,...,xn) of positive real numbers, we can find a sub-sequence that elements in this sub-sequence has a maximum product in O(n).

b) with an algorithm of order O(n) we can merge m=sqrt(n) sorted sequences that in whole we have n elements.

why my professor say these  two sentence is false?

i read an O(n) algorithms for (a):
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subarray/

anyone can help me?

Comment: would u please say what is the difference?

Comment: Dear @mu無, would you please a simple example ? i couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the first statement, but the second statement can be said false by the following argument:

Since there are sqrt(n) sequences, with n elements each, the total number of elements in n*sqrt(n). In the worst case, you would need to check every element at least once to merge them all into a single list, and this would put the time complexity at at least n*sqrt(n). If there are sqrt(n) elements in each sequence, please read the edit.

I'm not really sure about the first one because the algorithm provided by you is for integers, while we are dealing with reals in your case.

EDIT: A merging algorithm for k sorted arrays and n total elements puts the time complexity at O(n*log(k)). Even if every sequence has sqrt(n) elements (as opposed to n each, as assumed in the previous paragraph) the time complexity would still be O(n*(log(sqrt(n)))).

Comment: True that. I had just retained the sqrt(n) so that the OP would have a better idea of where that term was coming from.

Comment: would u please say sth about first one ?

Comment: would u please see:   http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9B39EDc29N4J:bigfoot.cs.upt.ro/~ioana/algo/lab_designindu.html+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ir

Comment: Maximum-product consecutive subsequence in above url

Comment: dear @mu無, would u please see this link :

Comment: as a result i think the (a) is true

Comment: it's wrong. the whole elements is n, sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)=n.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980818/how-to-sort-k-sorted-arrays-with-merge-sort

For n elements and k sorted arrays, min time is O(n\*log(k)). So, I had addressed what you said in the edit part of the question.

Comment: i know, you are wrong with this sentence: Since there are sqrt(n) sequences, with n elements each..., you should say Since there are sqrt(n) sequences, with sqrt(n) elements each...

Comment: I know. So the edit part of the answer relates to the case with sqrt(n) elements each. I have not removed the 'n' elements each part just because that could be another interpretation  of the question.