# comparing python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a very basic search engine in python, I am working on creating a method for handling phrase queries, so if the position of 2 words are within 1 they are next to each other in the document and it will output all document numbers where this happens.

I currently have a dictionary which looks like this

```
{'8':[['1170', '1264', '1307', '1559', '1638'], ['197', '1169']], 
 '6':[['345', '772'], ['346']}
```

This is just a layout example.

```
w=word, p=position ||
{doc1:[w1p1, w1p2, w1p3],[w2p1, w2p2]}
```

The key is the document id, followed by the positions in that document that the 1st word contains, then the positions of the 2nd word. There will be as many words (grouping of the positions) as that of in the query.

My questions is, is there a way were i can compare the values of the 1 and 2nd + 3rd etc ... values for the same document ID?. I want to compare them to see if a words position is only +1 of the other word.

So you can see for doc 6 word 2 follows word 1, this would result in the key being sent back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to achieve what you're trying to do here.  I'm assuming based on the example you gave me that there are always only two words, and the lists are always ordered ordered.

No matter what the method, you'll want to iterate over the documents (The dictionary).  Iterating over dictionaries is simple in Python; you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python).  After that, the steps change

**First option - less efficient, slightly simpler:**

1. Iterate over each item (location) in list 1 (the locations of the first word).
2. Iterate over each item (location) in list 2 (the locations of the second word).
3. Compare the two locations, and if they're within 1 of each other, return the document id.

   Example:

   ```
   for documentNumber in docdictionary:
       for word1location in docdictionary[documentNumber][0]:
           for word2location in docdictionary[documentNumber][1]:
               if abs(word1location - word2location) == 1:
                   return documentNumber
   ```

**Second Option - more efficient, slightly more complicated:**

1. Start at the beginning of each list of word locations, keeping track of where you are
2. Check the two values at the locations you're at.

   - If the two values are 1 word apart, return the document number
   - If the two values are not, check which list item (page position), has a lower value and move to the next item in that list, repeat
3. If one of the lists (ex. list 1) runs out of numbers, and the other list (list 2) is at a value that is greater than the last value of the first (list 1), return None.

   Example:

   ```
   for documentNumber in docdictionary:
       list1pos = 0
       list2pos = 0
       while True:
           difference = docdictionary[documentNumber][0][list1pos] - docdictionary[documentNumber][1][list2pos]
           if abs(difference) == 1:
               return documentNumber
           if difference < 0: #Page location 2 is greater
               list1pos++
               if list1pos == len(docdictionary[documentNumber][0]): #We were at the end of list 1, there will be no more matches
                   break
           else: #Page location 1 is greater
               list2pos++
               if list2pos == len(docdictionary[documentNumber][1]): #We were at the end of list 2, there will be no more matches
                   break
   return None
   ```

As a reminder, option 2 **only** works if the lists are **always** sorted.  Also, you don't always need to return the document id right away.  You could just add the document id to a list if you want all the documents that the pair happens in instead of the first one it finds.  You could even use a dictionary to easily keep track of how many times the word pair appears in each document.

Hope this helped!  Please let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: The amount of words can increase, as it's the amount of words in the query.

Comment: @simitar the second part of the answer implements the "merge" part of a "mergesort", it can generalized to an arbitrary number of lists.

Comment: @BiRico , how would i go about doing this as i would need to compare the position of 1 and 2 then the position of 2 and 3, and so on for as many words that are in the query.

Comment: @simitar I don't really understand your question. Is your question, "[how can I merge k sorted lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980818/how-to-sort-k-sorted-arrays-with-merge-sort)" or "what does mergesort have to do with my problem" or something else?

Comment: @BiRico, take this line 
difference = docdictionary[documentNumber][0][list1pos] - docdictionary[documentNumber][1][list2pos]

it compares the values from word 2 and 1 to see if they are next to each other. This works if a query has 2 words "hello there". If i have a query of three words such as "hello there today" i will need to check word 2 position against words 1position then word 3's position against 2

Comment: @simitar I'm not trying to start an argument with you, I really do want to help you but I don't know where you're stuck. With these kinds of problems the first step is to break apart the problem into smaller problems, preferably problems with well known solutions. Your problem is similar to, but not the same as a mergesort. The goal of mergesort is to take many small (often size 2-10) arrays or lists and merge them into one final sorted array or list. If you understand how a mergsort works, it might help you solve your problem.

Comment: @BiRico, sorry not trying to start an argument, just trying to get my problem across. Not sure how to word it.

Comment: @simitar the key here is to understand that in a mergsort, all consecutive items must be compared so that if the inputs look like this: `[[..., 8, ...], [..., 9, ...], [..., 10, ...]]`, the output must look like this `[..., 8, 9, 10, ...]`. You're not going to create the output, but you do want to go through the process of comparing all consecutive items in the combined inputs. Does that make sense? Actually your problem might be simplified a little because it seems like maybe you only need to compare consecutive items from 1 & 2, 2 & 3, 3 & 4 and so on.

Comment: @BiRico, I've figured out my problem, I was iterating the while loop the amount of words there is  - 1, however i used a while loops instead of a for loop and it was causing me errors. i've now used a for loop and it's working. Thank you for your efforts in helping.